# Android: Is the device rooted?

Tags: android

I have Android phone that fails to boot after working happily some time.

I'm trying to install official firmware update zip from manufacturer's site, but update fails with errors:

```
  E: footer is wrong
  E: signature verification failed
  E: install package error, result = 7
```

Google results suggest that official updates can fail integrity verification only if the device is rooted (yes, I've re-downloaded the update several times, the file is ok). As the phone does not boot, I cannot use the "root check" app or terminal etc. On top of the recovery menu, after the ROM version (I guess) there's a line: **user/test-keys**.

**Is this a sign that the device is rooted?**

Thanks,

-- ddbug

Comment: I think you should ask your question in [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you Atef. will post there.